# Why carousel hover is not working

Tags: jquery, hover, carousel

Here is my problem: I'm using a `.hover()` method for a jquery carousel to add some class and show/hide other divs with the same ID as (this). When hovering a slide element "do something". Everything works fine until carousel comes for the second round. I mean when first carousel item comes as last one then `.hover()` method doesn't work at all until this first item comes at his first place again.

My carousel look like this one: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php#responsive (it is responsive one)

Here is my `.hover()` function:

```
jQuery(' slide_element ').hover( function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).find("a").attr('id');
        // Show/Hide
        jQuery("#" + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
            $(" slide_element a ").removeClass('active');
            $(this).find("a").addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

One more time: everything works fine untill it comes for second round.

I met this problem before using the same carousel and  fancybox. Then I found a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your selector correct? - you don't seem to have a `.` or `#` before `slide_element`

Comment: It was an example. In my code there is other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code  . you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).
Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter',' slide_element ',function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).find("a").attr('id');
    // Show/Hide
    jQuery("#" + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
        $(" slide_element a ").removeClass('active');
        $(this).find("a").addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Now it works, but only with .on("click") . I don't know what is the problem but with hover it doesn't work.